# cgroups: cgclassify processes of other users

Tags: cgroups

As root I've create a cgroup which limits cpu and memory usage.

```
cgcreate -g cpu,memory:matlab_sandbox
cgset -r cpu.shares=250 matlab_sandbox
cgset -r memory.limit_in_bytes=8G matlab_sandbox
```

**Now I'm wondering why I can only enforce the limits on my own (root) processes.**

This works:

```
cgclassify -g cpu,memory:matlab_sandbox $(pgrep -U root matlab)
```

This doesn't work:

```
cgclassify -g cpu,memory:matlab_sandbox $(pgrep -U bob matlab)
```